# how to check exact row present in table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert new records in my table

it has 55 columns in total

so i need to check if some record already exist in table with same values in all 54 columns(except identity column)

I tried giving specific column names individually but its not feasible for all columns

Any suggestion will be appreciated :)

Comment: normally I would suggest creating a unique index, but I dont know how it will perform with that many columns

Comment: Try `INTERSECT` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 excluding id.

Comment: What is the reason why "its not feasible for all columns"? A select based on the values for the columns would be the way, if there's a result, the record exists..

Comment: 55 columns, unique? Seems like an odd db design.

Comment: No, it is feasible. The only thing standing in your way is laziness. You can, as Mike suggests, write code to overcome the laziness. But something somewhere must write that code. Get on with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to check this always and not only for this particular case, I can suggest you to create additional column with CHECKSUM of all the other columns and check new rows' checksum against already existing ones.

I hope this will work better then obvious idea of unique index for all the columns

Comment: And that checksum column should either be a computed column, or managed by triggers.

Comment: If many columns can be `NULL` then creating a good `CheckSum` might turn out difficult I guess

Comment: Yes, it should be computed column with unique index on it, so you don't need to check it manually or with triggers

Answer (score 0):

Select the columns from the sys tables and genereate an sql statement with group by clause like this example here:

```
declare @tbl varchar(255) = 'your_table' -- <<<< your table

declare @tmp nvarchar(max) = ''

select @tmp = @tmp + column_name + ', ' 
from (SELECT o.name as table_name 
    ,c.name AS column_name  
    ,c.column_id   
FROM sys.columns AS c   
join sysobjects as o on c.object_id=o.id
where o.name = @tbl
and c.name not in ('id', 'add_date', 'edit_date') -- <<<< fields you don't want to compare
) as t1

declare @fields nvarchar(max) = (select substring(@tmp, 0, len(@tmp)))

declare @string nvarchar(max) = N'select ' + @fields + ', count(id) as no, min(id) as first_id, max(id) as last_id from dbo.' + @tbl + ' group by ' + @fields + ' having count(id)>1'
exec (@string)
```

as result you have all colums with additional the number of equal rows, the first (min) id and the last (max) id.

Answer (score 0):

Add a hash as persisted computed column

```
ALTER TABLE [YourTable]
ADD [HASH]  AS (CONVERT([bigint]
                       ,hashbytes('MD5'
                                 ,concat([Col 1],'|'
                                        ,[Col ...],'|'
                                        ,[Col i],'|'
                                        ,[Col ...],'|'
                                        ,[Col 54],'|'
                                        )
                                 )
                       )
               )
PERSISTED
```

and then make a Unique Index on that Column